# Can anyone explain, or speak to how I can remove, these greyed out windows when I launch a terminal group (see screenshot)

Tags: terminal, group

For some odd reason, when I launch a terminal group via

`Terminal > Window > Open Window Group > Select from list`

I am greeted by the terminal group AND a bunch of greyed out windows, often numbering greater than the number of tabs I am opening... I have saved and re-saved the group, I do not select "restore all commands" but they keep popping up. And, further, it's not every time... Once my terminal is running and I open a group, there tend to not be grey windows... I haven't quite figured out if there's a pattern yet :S Sometimes they appear behind the actual temrinal, sometimes foregrounded...

It's a livable problem, I just close them but what the heck is going on here?

[image]

Comment: do you have any Preferences->Profiles names that begin with a dot (.)?

Comment: not that I can see, the profiles under Preferences>Profiles are stock from OSX